# A little help to understand Database.query

Tags: apex

can someone help me understand what is happening in this snippet of code? It seems to me to be a SOQL query but I'm not sure, I'm new with Apex. I have 3 classes that refer to each other, I'll go here in detail:

```
loginsite.apx


global PageReference login() {
        String startUrl = System.currentPageReference().getParameters().get('startURL');
        String token;
        SiteUser__c user; 

user = aSiteAuthManager.UserLogin(username,password);        
        if(user == null){
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,Label.Username_incorrent));
            return null;
        }
```

```
aSiteAuthManager.apx
public class aSiteAuthManager {
    
    public aSiteAuthManager() {
    }

    public static SiteUser__c UserLogin(String us, String pass){

        SiteUser__c[] users = aSiteUtils.queryResults3(SiteUser__c.SObjectType, null, 'Password__c = :v1', pass, 'Email__c = :v2',us, 'Active__c = :v3', true);
        if(users.size() > 0)
            return users[0];
        else
            return null;
    }    
}
```

```
aSiteUtils.apx

public static SObject[] queryResults3(SObjectType entity, String queryPlus, String fn1, Object v1, String fn2, Object v2, String fn3, Object v3){
    return Database.query(queryFromSObject(entity,queryPlus)+' where ' + fn1 + ' and ' + fn2 + ' and ' + fn3 + ' Order By Name');
}
```

The real doubt is to understand this function 'Database.query' what it does..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Apex we have two ways to perform queries, static and dynamic.

#### Static queries

generally look like
`List<SObject> results = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = :Date.today().addDays(-4)];`
are what most people use most of the time.

Because it's part of the syntax of Apex, the compiler Salesforce uses can perform checks to ensure that you're storing the results in a collection of an appropriate type, that the object specified in the `FROM` part actually exists, that the fields specified in the `SELECT` part exist on that SObject, etc...

#### Dynamic queries

`Database.query()` is used to execute dynamic queries, and you pass a string into the method that contains the query you want to execute.

Any static query can be run as a dynamic query (though some additional work can be required when you use "variable binds", i.e. the  `:Date.today().addDays(-4)` bit)

```java
Date targetDate = Date.today().addDays(-4);
// You can't use dot-notation in variable binds in dynamic queries
List<SObject> results = Database.query('SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate = :targetDate');
```

but you generally don't want to run a dynamic query if you can make it a static query.

Dynamic queries are useful when you don't know about what some part of the query will be until you actually run the code. Things like what fields you want to query or which SObject you're querying against.

Consider the following, which you can execute via anonymous apex

```java
public List<SObject> generalQuery(String SObjectName){
    return Database.query(String.format(
        // The "N_DAYS_AGO:4" bit is a "Date literal"
        'SELECT Id FROM {0} WHERE CreatedDate > N_DAYS_AGO:4',
        new List<String>{ SObjectName }
    ));

    // Alternatively, you could use simple string concatenation, but I feel it
    //   gets unwieldly pretty quickly, and you have to be very conscious about
    //   including whitespace where it's needed
    // e.g. after the 'FROM' and before the 'WHERE'
    //return Database.query('SELECT Id FROM ' + SObjectName + ' WHERE CreatedDate > N_DAYS_AGO:4');
}

// The (List<Account>)/(List<Opportunity>) bit before the method name is explicit type
//   casting
// A query that can work on multiple SObjects can only return a more generic type.
// If you want/need a List<Account>, for example, then you need to typecast to tell Apex
//   "I know you _think_ this is a List<SObject>, but it's really a List<Account>, trust me"
List<Account> accountList = (List<Account>)generalQuery('Account');
List<Opportunity> opportunityList = (List<Opportunity>)generalQuery('Opportunity');
```

We could have written 2 separate queries here, but the method allows us to re-use a single query. This isn't a good example of when to use a dynamic query (this example would be shorter if we did write two separate, static queries), but the takeaway is that *you use dynamic queries when it's difficult or impossible to know the entire query before code starts executing*.

#### Your case

If you look at the result of calling the `queryFromSObject()` method, you should see that it will return a string like `SELECT Id, Some_Field__c, Other_Field__c FROM SiteUser__c`.

`queryFromSObject()` itself probably looks like

```java
    String objectName = mySObjectType.getDescribe().getName();
    // Given an SObject type, we can get all of its field api names
    List<String> fields = mySObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();

    // String.join() can take a list of strings and turn it into a single string,
    //   with each individual string separated by a seperator you specify
    // i.e. ['Field1__c', 'Field2__c'] => 'Field1__c, Field2__c'
    return 'SELECT ' + String.join(fields, ', ') + ' FROM ' + objectName;
```

You're then tacking  `WHERE <filter 1> AND <filter 2> AND <filter 3> ORDER BY Name` onto that to give you the complete query.

This complete query is passed to `Database.query()`, which then interprets the string and executes the query.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, your code is just dynamically building a query, presumably to select all fields, and accepting three filter conditions. The [Database.query](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_database.htm#apex_System_Database_query) method accepts a valid SOQL string, performs the query, and then returns a list of objects that match the query, which can be a typical `sObject` record (e.g. `Account` or `MyCustomObject__c`) or an `AggregateResult` when using the `GROUP BY` SOQL options.

Answer (score 1):

The Database.query() method is used to make [dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) in which we pass a SOQL string and the system returns the result of the query. The inner methods in the Database.query in your code is helping in creating the SOQL string.